# why innerHTML dosen't work inside setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```
$(document).ready(function () {
counter.innerHTML = "3";
var t1 = setTimeout(function () { counter.innerHTML = "2"; }, 1000);
var t2 = setTimeout(function () { counter.innerHTML = "1"; }, 1000);
var t3 = setTimeout(function () { counter.innerHTML = null; }, 1000);
});
```

hello, why innerHTML dosen't work inside setTimeout for me? is there a better why to count down?
 thanks!

Comment: what is counter? is it defined?

Comment: Those timeouts all fire "at once". In effect, only t3 remains standing. Try @JasonYang's answer.

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. Setting `innerHTML` works just fine (assuming `counter` is actually defined): http://jsfiddle.net/Zgjh7/. Note that I replaced `null` with a different value so that you can actually see that the assignment works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
counter.innerHTML = "3";
var t1 = setTimeout(function () { counter.innerHTML = "2"; }, 1000);
var t2 = setTimeout(function () { counter.innerHTML = "1"; }, 2000);
var t3 = setTimeout(function () { counter.innerHTML = null; }, 3000);
});
```

try this

Comment: You should use a recursive function instead.

Comment: I know,i use this just want let him know why his code didn't work

Comment: Thank you very much. It's my first time I'm asking here a question, next time I will be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make it recursive which enable you to easily change the number to count down:

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/GfPn5/)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function countDown(num) {
        if (num > 0) {
            counter.innerHTML = num.toString();
            setTimeout(function(){countDown(num-1)}, 1000);
        }
    }

    countDown(3);
});
```

You can extend it so that when the count down is done you use a callback function:

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO EXT.](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/J8kA7/)**</kbd>

```
function countDown(num, callback) {
    if (num > 0) {
        counter.innerHTML = num.toString();
        setTimeout(function(){countDown(num-1, callback)}, 1000);
    } else {
        callback()
    }
}
countDown(3, function() {alert('Done!')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
function createCountdown(count){
    counter.innerHTML = count ? count : null;
    if(count--){
        setTimeout(function(){createCountdown(count);}, 1000);
    }
}
createCountdown(3);
```

Your code doesn't work is because all of the `setTimeout` are fired at the same time.